# how to stop this gunicorn server?

Tags: gunicorn

I tried almost all commands to kill gunicorn server.  but nothing is working. how can i kill these processes and free 80 port

```
12652 ?        Ss     0:00 sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 foss.wsgi:application
12654 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 foss.wsgi:application
12659 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 foss.wsgi:application
12709 ?        Ss     0:00 sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 foss.wsgi:application
12711 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 foss.wsgi:application
12717 pts/11   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

Comment: Are you using supervisor or something to manage the gunicorn processes? I presume something is auto restarting it

Comment: i don't know about supervising.. but it is auto restarting. how can i stop that ? should i have to uninstall gunicorn?

Comment: @Sayse i uninstalled the gunicorn now 
15982 pts/11   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
is only running. so i used sudo kill -9 15982. but now it is restarting onto another number

Comment: gunicorn can be installed in virtualenvs so something is probably still running it

Answer (score 6):

Grab the pid, for example 12652 here, and issue this command:

```
sudo kill -9 12652
```

That will issue a [SIGKILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL), which can not be caught or ignored by an application.

If the server just starts up again immediately after, it means there's some process control system or init scripts such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) configured on the box, which is managing the service and can [autorestart when the service goes down](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/8cb2bd2329a94c6f22f35f3ee5f1d725ab798101/examples/supervisor.conf#L5).

You'll have to disable it in the process control system, e.g. `supervisord stop yourapp`.

Comment: I tried this command to each number like 12652 12654 etc. but after that server is starting on another numers like 15396, 15371 etc

Comment: Then you have some watchdog restarting it, you'll have to find that service and stop it